# how to capture p elements value when click event happened using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I want to capture Nebula and Price 1.44 when I click on button. Can anyone help me please.

Html code

```
           <div class="item__top">
                <p> Nebula</p>
                <p>
                    Price<span class="big-price">1</span>.44
                    <span class="text-large">/mo</span>
                </p>
                <p>$2.88</p>
                
                <button class="calculate-hosting">Get Started</button>
                <p>You pay $17.28 — Renews at $33.88/year</p>
            </div>
```

JS code

```
var calHosting = document.querySelectorAll('.calculate-hosting');
[...calHosting].forEach(cal=>{
    cal.addEventListener('click',function(event){

        document.getElementById('cal-container').style.display='block';

    });
});

Note: I am dealing with mutiple buttons so thats why I sued querySelectorAll.
```

Comment: yes. I just want to print Nebula and 1.44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` to refer to the button that was clicked, `.parentElement` to climb up, and then select paragraphs and their inner text. The text can be parsed however you like from there.

```js
var calHosting = document.querySelectorAll('.calculate-hosting');
[...calHosting].forEach(cal => {
    cal.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var paragraphs = this.parentElement.querySelectorAll("p");
        var p1 = paragraphs[0].innerText;
        var p2 = paragraphs[1].innerText;
        var price = Number(p2.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]);
        
        console.log(p1); // Nebula
        console.log(p2); // Price1.44 /mo
        console.log(price); // 1.44
        
        // document.getElementById('cal-container').style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="item__top">
    <p> Nebula</p>
    <p>
        Price<span class="big-price">1</span>.44
        <span class="text-large">/mo</span>
    </p>
    <p>$2.88</p>

    <button class="calculate-hosting">Get Started</button>
    <p>You pay $17.28 — Renews at $33.88/year</p>
</div>
```